# Replace characters in MySQL query result PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Couldn't find an exact answer to this question on here, though it may be simple (if there is an answer please point me in the right direction).

I am pulling some data from MySQL and some of the characters are causing the data not to be displayed at the end point.  I therefore need to single out these specific characters and replace them with a permitted character.  Specifically I need to change & , ' and + .  I have to do this working from this query:

```
$query = "select * from data where a_data_id=".$ID." AND a_discard_data_from!=1";
```

I was wondering if I can add to this string, or after this string, some rule to replace instances & , ' or + with another character/s.

Thanks for looking!

NOTE:  There is no problem with the string above, it is functioning fine, I just want to add to it or after it some type of code that will replace certain characters in the data pulled from the query

Surrounding Code:

```
$arr="";
$main_arr="";
$query = "select * from data where a_data_id=".$ID." AND a_discard_data_from!=1";
$query .=" and last_update >= " . '"' . $dataDate . '"';
$table = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($table) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $arr[$key] = $value;
            if ($key == "to_data_id") {    
               $array=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select name,additional from details where data_id=".$value));
                $arr["data_id"] = $array['additional'].".".$array['name'];
            }
        }
        $main_arr[] = $arr;
    }
}



$data = json_encode($main_arr);
```

Just how to slow it into this code would be great, thank you!  (This code works fine, just want to know what I could change / add to replace those characters).

UPDATE:  Is anyone able to give me an answer with how I might be able to use strtr()function to replace the results please?  Thanks again for the responses!

Comment: What is the end point on which the data is being displayed?  Perhaps it would (architecturally) make more sense to handle presentational matters of this sort (that are specific to an end point) closer to the end point itself than in the database layer?  Indeed, it may well be that the end point has a library function or similar to handle/encapsulate/encode characters that it cannot display.

Comment: Yes, that is true but for certain reasons I can not change that at this stage - I need to work with this query which sends the data directly to the application so need to work with the query and wanted to know if there is some type of code I could use to replace the retrieved data while it is being passed on.  Thanks

Comment: How is it that you're able to edit the query but not the code that is dispatching the query?

Comment: You can use [strtr() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace those in PHP after you gather the results.

Comment: Oh, the data is passed from php to an application, I can edit the PHP but not the application right now.  If you have any idea it would be really appreciated!  I can add the whole section of code if you like, but I think this is the most important part which I have already added above.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks inhan - I will add the rest of the code above and please give me an example, just a sec.

Comment: You need to answer the answer @eggyal's first question, what does it need to be encoded for, urls, js, etc.? The fact that you have found 3 characters that break the application, does not mean it is limited to 3 only.

Comment: Those are the three that I can identify and have tested, so I will be happy to replace those at this stage then replace any others if I find them to be causing any problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql if you manually select a field after selecting * it overwrites that field, so provided there's only one field you want to run replaces on and you know the field you know which field it is in advance you can change your select query to (the somewhat ungraceful):

```
"select 
     *, 
     REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
             REPLACE(`data`.`YOURFIELDNAME`, '&', 'A'),
         ',', 'A'),
     '\'', 'A') 
 from 
     data 
 where a_data_id=".$ID." AND a_discard_data_from!=1";
```

Which will remove those characters. This is not very graceful, and as eggyal pointed out, you're better off doing this on the front end.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need at the moment! Thank you!  In what you wrote, what is replacing what?  & is replaced with ,?  (yes, it is just in the one column, called the_data)  What is the A for?  Just trying to figure how this works, thanks!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, I see, A is what it is changed to, THANKS!

Comment: Sorry, I tried this over and over again for the past hour or so and it just will not work - I need to replace the string of data coming out of MySQL before it's passed to the application.

Comment: It just doesn't do what it supposed to do and actually causes the whole process to stall ... not sure why.  I have tried it using just one replace request and in many different parts, really tried to get it to work, but even when the process stops stalling, it doesn't work so there must be something going wrong.. See this code pulls data from our MySQL DB on the server and sends it to the app - but for some reason, the changes you suggested are not replacing the values they're meant to look out for and replace.  Not sure if you can thinking of something else? THanks all the same

Comment: I've corrected a small error with the escaping which may have been causing the problems.